# HTML Button Not redirecting into given link in Java mail body

Tags: java, html, button, onclick

I want to add a button to HTML email template I'm creating. 
I already created a button but when I click on it, the link does not appear. 
Can anyone help me with my problem?

Here is my code:

```
messageBodyPart.setContent("<h1>You Have a Promotion</h1> <h3>Your First Name :</h3>" + FirstNm + 
                      "<h3>Your Last Name :</h3>" + LastNm + "<h3>Your Employee ID :</h3>" + Employeeid + 
                      " <br/> <form>\r\n" + 
                            "<input class=\"MyButton\" onclick =\"http://localhost:8080/update/status/password/ACCEPT\" type = \"button\" value =\"Accept Your Promotion\" />\r\n" + 
                      "</form>","text/html");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add anchor tags and with an `href` attribute instead of an `onclick` event on the `input` element.

```
messageBodyPart.setContent("<h1>You Have a Promotion</h1> <h3>Your First Name :</h3>" + FirstNm + 
                      "<h3>Your Last Name :</h3>" + LastNm + "<h3>Your Employee ID :</h3>" + Employeeid + 
                      " <br/> <form>\r\n" + 
                            "<a href=\"http://localhost:8080/update/status/password/ACCEPT\"><input class=\"MyButton\"  type = \"button\" value =\"Accept Your Promotion\" /></a>\r\n" + 
                      "</form>","text/html");
```

Comment: Do you know can i add some styles in Bootstrap into a mail body

Answer (score 0):

You can use input like this:
`<input type="button" onclick="window.location='https://www.yourdomain.com/'" value='Go'>`

```html
<html>
 <head></head>
 
 <body>
 
  <input type="button" onclick="window.location='https://www.yourdomain.com/'" value='Go'>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: do i want to remove the <form> </form> tags?

Comment: Yes... you can loose it.